# Analytic Continuation of Sum of Delta Functions

Tags: mathematical-physics, analytic-continuation

Let's say I have the following expression:

$$f(n) = \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \delta(\tau -m  )$$

Now, for integer $n$ this is simple enough, but I'm interested in analytically continuing this function to non-integer $n$. Is there some easy way to do this, maybe with the Fourier transformed version of the $\delta$ function? I'm particularly interested in the case where $n \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: The Dirac Delta is NOT a function.  It is a distribution.  So analytic continuation does not apply here.

Comment: Would it make it better if I took the delta function as a limit of an appropriate function like a Gaussian?

Comment: You are asking if it might be useful to use a regularization of the Dirac Delta (NOT a function).

Comment: Yes, exactly that. I'm also wondering if this is a thing people do, analytically continuing a discrete sum of functions (which I recognize doesn't include my case but I'd like to look at for inspiration)

Comment: So, look at the sum $\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\delta_k(\tau -m)$, where $\delta_k(x)$ is a regularized Dirac Delta such that in distribution $\lim_{k\to\infty}\delta_k(x)\sim \delta(x)$.  Now how do you propose to proceed?

Comment: Ah, I may have hit on something. Is it possible to transform $f(n)$ (either Fourier or Laplace transform), compute the sum explicitly for arbitrary $n$, and transform back?

Comment: The upper limit $n$ is not a continuous variable.  You can apply the FT or LT to $\tau$, but not to $n$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115147/discussion-between-sean-and-mark-viola).